# I can't write anything in other partitions (as regular user)

Tags: linux, files, linux-mint, filesystems

I use Linux Mint on a dual boot with Windows 10.

Problem is I can't write/modify "cut or delete and so on" any data on other partitions. When I use Linux I can only write to my file system, but when using Windows I can write anywhere.

What should I do to write to other partitions when using linux?

**When I click properties at partition it tells me: "*you are not the owner*".**

[image: Image1]

**When I click properties of some folders I can't cut or delete**.

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1):

The default [login](http://www.linfo.org/login_def.html) for Linux Mint is as a regular user, (suppose that user name is "*ak*"), and user *ak*'s write permissions are usually only for what's in [`/home/ak`](http://www.linfo.org/home_directory.html).  The other partitions are not in `/home/ak`.

In Linux, writing to other partitions usually requires logging in as [*root*](http://www.linfo.org/root.html).

Comment: Or mounting the partition with the correct permissions.